# Remote Jupyter notebook server disconnects and crashes semi-randomly

Tags: python, ssh, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, remote-server

I have a home server, which I use to run Jupyter.

I open a terminal window on my macbook and login into the server using `ssh username@home-server`. I then start jupyter using `jupyter notebook --no-browser`. I then open another terminal window on my macbook and set up Jupyter server port forwarding `ssh -L 8000:localhost:8888 username@home-server`. Then I can open a browser on my mac, navigate to localhost:8000 with the right token, and everything works.

But!

Periodically, the Jupyter server disconnects and the terminal window I used to set up port forwarding starts printing "Connection refused" messages. When I re-open the terminals and re-ssh-login into the server, it shows no Jupyter notebooks running. This is puzzling, as I would expect Jupyter to keep running on the remote server, even if I lose the internet connection to it.

Similarly, if I close my macbook and it goes to sleep, the Jupyter notebook also somehow dies on the remote server.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong? The server is running OpenSUSE Leap.

Thanks!